# Отправка запроса на WCF сервер через http (WebClient)

Tags: c#, http, wcf

Всем привет! Пытаюсь направить запрос на WCF-сервер через WebClient.
Вот так выглядит целевой метод сервера

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method="POST",
  ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
  RequrstFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
  BodyStyle = WebMassageBodyStyle.Bare,
  UriTemplate = "post"
)]
string DoWork(MethodParams methodParams);
```

Вот так я отправляю запрос

```
var webClient = new WebClient();
var response = webClient.UploadString(url, "POST", **data**);
```

Теперь проблема.
Если переменная **data** содержит такой json

```
var data = "{\"par\":\"{}\"}";
```

То сервер спокойно принимает запрос и возвращает результат работы. Если в параметр **par** передавать непустой объект, а имеющий какие-то поля, как здесь

```
var data = "{\"par\":\"{\"innerPar\":1}\"}";
```

то сервер вернет ошибку "(400) Недопустимый запрос". Обратите внимание, что значение **par** экранировано как **строка**.
Вопросы:
1. Почему так происходит?
2. Как мне отправить запрос, содержащий json с полем, значение которого строка, в которой содержится json-объект (как во втором значение переменной **data**)?

**P/S** Менять настройки целевого метода - не вариант, он должен оставаться таким как я его привел.

Comment: [json null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21120999/representing-null-in-json)

Comment: JSON для примера, я такой не отправляю. Суть в другом {par: "{}"} проходит, а {par:"{innerPar:1}"} - нет

Comment: @AndreiS. У вас неверная строка, любой десериализатор не поймет подобное. Я так понимаю, что в `par` должна быть JSON строка? Если да, то у вас она должна быть экранирована по другому `var data = "{\"par\":\"{\\\"innerPar\\\":null}\"}";`

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Спасибо, проблема была здесь. Я так понял, что при моем экранировании парсер WCF`а воспринимал значение par никак строку, а как объект и пытался его парсить, как вы думаете?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Давайте возьмем вашу строку `{\"par\":\"{\"innerPar\":1}\"}`. Вы ее экранизировали для того, что бы "загнать" в `string`, отлично.

Сделаем обратное, уберем все `\`. Что получаем: `{"par":"{"innerPar":1}"}`. В таком варианте, любой десериализатор не сможет понять что от него хотят, ибо тут примерно тоже самое, что и с экранизацией в `string`, вы говорите, что в `par` содержится `string` (указав это двойными скобками), но в тоже время засовываете в него еще объект, который содержит двойные скобки. Это не правильно.

Как решить задачу: А все просто, вам надо отправить сделать так, что бы в `JSON`, который получит сервер, строка была уже экранизирована и имела формат: `{"par":"{\"innerPar\":1}"}`. Для этого, при отправки на сервер, вам надо переписать строку отправки следующим способом: `"{\"par\":\"{\\\"innerPar\\\":1}\"}"`.

Вообще, я не советовал бы отправлять `JSON` в `JSON`, не правильно это что ли...

Comment: Еще раз спасибо за ваш ответ. Да идея засовывать JSON в JSON не самая лучшая, согласен, но дело  в том, что это данность с которой приходится считаться. Это некий запрос, который приходит на сервер и  в случае провала должен быть сохранен, а затем отправлен еще раз, но уже без участия клиента. Гарантированное завершение платежной транзакции.